# Change StaticText background color dynamically with JasperReports API

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I would like to change the background color of Static text programmatically, nothing happened, but `setForecolor` is working (change the font color).

for example:

```
JRDesignStaticText _StaticText = new JRDesignStaticText();
// setForecolor is working
_StaticText.setForecolor(java.awt.Color.green);
//but setBackcolor not working
_StaticText.setBackcolor(java.awt.Color.red);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background color is applied when the element is opaque.  So you need to also do

```
_StaticText.setMode(ModeEnum.OPAQUE);
```